# How to get the screenshot of a minimized application programmatically?

Tags: c#, screenshot, minimize

I'm trying to get the screenshot of a minimized application, any ideas of how to it under windows ? I'm using C#

tks in advance,
Jose

Answer (score 3):

Restore, take the screenshot, minimize back...

If it is not on screen, I don't see how you can make a copy of the image...

Answer (score 2):

On Vista and later, this should be possible with the Desktop Window Manager. Explorer also displays (animated) screenshots of minimized windows when hovering over a taskbar entry with DWM enabled, so the DWM APIs should be the way to go.

Out of curiosity, why do you need such a screenshot?

Comment: Simple :) I need to screencast a lot of applications at once on the same machine, I cannot have them all maximized at the same time :)

Comment: In that case, the DWM should be your friend, since the naive approach PhiLho describes won't work very well, especially if you want to work on the system at the same time. If you're on XP or earlier, I think you're out of luck.

Answer (score 0):

It's easy. Just use the printWindow Api call!