# How does VNC continuously repaint windows?

Tags: c#, windows, remote-desktop, vnc, vnc-server

How does VNC send REPAINT messages to windows even when a user is not active?

I would like to implement this in C sharp - I've had a look at the `PrintWindow`, `SendMessage` methods and none of them achieve the same thing as VNC (tested by capturing images and its black) but with VNC I get the full picture.

What techniques are they using to do this and can this be implemented in C sharp to get windows to always repaint **even** when a user is not active (i.e. RDP is closed, minimised or similar).

Thanks all

Comment: I don't understand why you think `PrintWindow` is failing. The way I understand your question, that should do exactly what you want. I'm not really sure what you mean when you describe VNC as "continuously repainting windows".

Comment: @Cody - that's what I thought too until I tried it `PrintWindow(handle, hDC, 0);` - it failed to capture an image when I minimised an RDP connection to my windows XP machine. It works when RDP is not minimised. I thought I could capture the window image from memory but all it produced was a window with the insides black. I tried it for different types of windows (notepad, calc). I then installed VNC and I closed the VNC viewer and it worked each time. It some how gets windows to render even if the user is inactive.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use the technique used by video games, which consists in redrawing permanently a window during CPU idle time.

I found a C# implementation [here](http://slimdx.org/tutorials/basicwindow.php).

You just have to adapt it to your needs.

Comment: Very interesting, I need to read up on it first, I don't want to go all out yet!

Answer (score 0):

VNC does *NOT* send WM_PAINT messages

Windows does (and it does not care whether a user is active). See also

[Is it possible to screenshot a minimized application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3251104/is-it-possible-to-screenshot-a-minimized-application)

[How to get the screenshot of a minimized application programmatically?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/773398/how-to-get-the-screenshot-of-a-minimized-application-programmatically)

[Capturing screenshots of a minimized remote desktop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3437453/capturing-screenshots-of-a-minimized-remote-desktop)

Comment: Hmm, you're drawing a different conclusion than the one which is drawn by the answers to the questions you link to. You're right that VNC doesn't send `WM_PAINT` messages, but that doesn't imply that Windows sends this message when a user is not active. The solutions to those other questions either involve `PrintWindow`, or taking advantage of the new painting features introduced with DWM.